# Button text dissappears after paint event executes

Tags: c#

This is very strange. When I do this in my button's paint event:

```
using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(button1.ClientRectangle,
                                                               Color.Orange,
                                                               Color.Red,
                                                               90F))
{
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
}
```

the text of the button disappears. How can I get the text back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically drawing over the top of the control. You should try sub-classing the button and overriding `OnPaintBackground` to paint behind the text.

Answer (score 0):

Why not setting the Background brush of the button ?

Comment: As far as I remember you can't just do it like that with Windows Forms.

Comment: Okay, thought it was WPF sorry

Answer (score 0):

1. Call `button1.Invalidate()`. This will redraw text... and whole button.
2. Previous advice may produce not what you want. Since you decided to paint button by yourself, you will also be responsible for drawing text on top of your background, see `DrawString`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the background property or override the OnPaintBackground method, you can do the following:

//Your background painting code

```
public void DrawText(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, string text, Font font, Brush brush)
{
   float x = bounds.Width / 2;
   float y = bounds.Height /2;

   SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString(text, font);

   x = (x - (textSize.Width / 2) + bounds.X);
   y = (x - (textSize.Height / 2) + bounds.Y);

   g.DrawString(text, font, brush, new PointF(x, y));
}
```

and use it like so

```
DrawText(g, button1.ClientRectangle, button1.Text, button1.Font, new SolidBrush(button1.ForeColor));
```

None of this is actually tested though sooooo yeaaaa....

EDIT: If you choose to go this route, you will have to keep in mind that when the control is resized, it would require a repaint of the control.